# How to hide/show duplicate element with a search filter?

Tags: jquery

I have a filter, which find the sought value.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="my-textbox" placeholder="filtering..." />
<table id="Table">
<tr>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script>
$(".my-textbox").keyup(function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
    var seen = {};


    $("#Table tr").each(function() {
        var content = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text();

        if (content.toUpperCase().indexOf(value) == -1) {
            $(this).hide();     
        } else {
            $(this).show();

        }

        /* Remove duplicate */
        var txt = $(this).text();
        if (seen[txt])
            $(this).remove();
        else
            seen[txt] = true;

    });
});
</script>
```

The table contains four elements, 1 2 3 1. If I write 1 in the search input, the result is **1** and the duplicate element (e.g. the 4th element) is removed.

**How to solve that after each filtering the duplicate element (e.g. the 4th element) to be visible again?**

The point is that if I delete the searching element from the input, then showing all elements of table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this snippet, idea is first lets save the actual result in some variable, if textbox doesn't have any text then fill the result with actual data.

```js
var actualResult;
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     actualResult=$(".myResult").html(); 
});

$(".my-textbox").keyup(function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
    var seen = {};

    if($('.my-textbox').val().length<=0)
    {    
         $(".myResult").html(actualResult); return; 
    }
        
    $("#Table tr").each(function() {
        var content = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text();

        if (content.toUpperCase().indexOf(value) == -1) {
            $(this).hide();     
        } else {
            $(this).show();
        }       
        

        /* Remove duplicate */
        var txt = $(this).text();
        if (seen[txt])
            $(this).remove();
        else
            seen[txt] = true;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="my-textbox" placeholder="filtering..." />
<div class='myResult'> 
<table id="Table">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```